# What's the correct null and alternative hypothesis?

Tags: statistics

For the scenario below, write down the most appropriate null and alternative hypotheses that you would use for statistical inference on the population mean. Write down the critical value that you would use to run your test. Choose a significance level for the test of 5%.

Mercury levels higher than two parts per billion in drinking water are unsafe. You are responsible for determining whether drinking water in a given city is safe, based on 100 water samples that have been taken from different areas of that city.

My idea is that the null is that Mercury level is three or higher than three, which means that drinking water is unsafe. The alternative is that Mercury level is less than three, which means that water is safe for drinking. If we find evidence against null, we can reject null and conclude that water is safe for drinking. However, in group discussions, my classmates get different ideas from me.

Comment: Could you edit into the question your own thoughts so far?

Answer (score 1):

The choice of null and alternative hypothesis depends on **which claim requires the burden of proof**.

A commonly used analogy comes from the legal doctrine of "innocent until proven guilty."  In a jury trial, defendants are presumed innocent, and are only convicted if there is guilt "beyond a reasonable doubt."  This means the evidence weighing in favor of guilt must be so overwhelming that it is highly implausible to a reasonable person that the defendant could still be innocent in light of the evidence presented.

The rationale for this doctrine is that it is a far greater miscarriage of justice to wrongly convict an innocent person than it is to fail to convict the guilty on the basis of inadequate evidence of guilt.  Consequently, such a legal system would prefer to reduce the likelihood of the former than the latter.

In hypothesis testing, a similar notion applies to the null and alternative hypotheses, with the null being "innocence" and the alternative being "guilt."  Therefore, which claim is the null and which is the alternative depends on which one, if true, requires the data to show with a high degree of confidence.  Correspondingly, the only conclusions that are possible in a statistical hypothesis test are:

1. Reject the null hypothesis (i.e., accept the alternative)
2. Fail to reject the null hypothesis (i.e., the evidence is inconclusive).

It is a common misconception to characterize the second conclusion as being equivalent to "accepting the null hypothesis."  This is wrong because the entire test is performed under the presumption of the null, just as a jury trial is held under the presumption of innocence:  the prosecutor will argue "if the defendant is innocent, then how could all the evidence point to their guilt?"

To further extend the analogy, a conclusion in which we reject the null hypothesis in error is analogous to a defendant being wrongfully convicted.  This error is called Type I error, and we design the test in such a way as to limit the probability of making such an error to not exceed some predefined value called $\alpha$, the significance level of the test.  Conversely, the failure to reject the null when the alternative is true, is called a Type II error, and is analogous to the failure to convict a guilty defendant.

---

With all of this in mind, we now turn our attention to your specific question.  Here, you are presented with a scenario in which we very clearly want to conclusively demonstrate that the water is safe--in other words, the penalty for erroneously claiming the water is safe when it is not, is quite a lot higher than the cost of claiming the water is unsafe when it is.  Consider that many people could be severely poisoned or permanently harmed in the former case.  So the former error is the one that must be tightly controlled.  Consequently, the claim that requires the burden of proof is the claim that the water is safe.  This must be your alternative hypothesis.  Therefore, the correct structure of the hypothesis test is

$$H_0 : \mu \ge 2 \quad \text{vs.} \quad H_1 : \mu < 2.$$

Under the assumption of the null being true, the choice of test statistic will be based on a null mean of $\mu_0 = 2$, since this is the choice that will ensure that the Type I error of the test will not exceed the significance level--i.e., it is the most conservative and ensures that if we reject $H_0$, we do so in error with probability at most $\alpha$.

Comment: very nice analogy

Answer (score 1):

In NHST, at the end of the day, you will either have statistical evidence for the alternative hypothesis, or nothing. So the alternative hypothesis is better something you are interested in showing!

If you want to be able to tell people with confidence: "Yes, you can drink this water", choose $H_1\colon \mu < 2$. If you want to be able to tell the city with confidence "You have a mercury problem", choose $H_1\colon \mu > 2$. An appropriate null-hypothesis to be tested against is $H_0: \mu=2$ in both cases.

The text "You are responsible determining whether drinking water in a given city is safe" indicates that you want to be able to tell people with confidence: "Yes, you can drink this water", and you choose $H_1\colon \mu < 2$.

Comment: do not forget that we are assuming normality, that is a distribution symmetric around 2 and with a variance $<0.36$ (merury containts cannot be negative). So empirically I think there are no different results when analyzing left or right tail of the Gaussian (this is only My Humble Opinion, of course)

Answer (score 0):

> Mercury levels higher than two parts per billion in drinking water are unsafe.

Reading the statement, the obvious system of hypothesis to be verified is the following

$$\begin{cases}
\mathcal{H}_0,  & \mu=2 \\
\mathcal{H}_1,  & \mu>2
\end{cases}$$

as the test is One Tailed, and considering that $n=100$ is greater enough, you will use the following statistic

$$Z_{stat}=\frac{\overline{X}_{100}-2}{S}\sqrt{100}\dot{\sim}N(0;1)$$

and you will Reject $\mathcal{H}_0$ (EDIT: $H_0 \leq2$ means **the water is safe**) iff

$$Z_{stat}\geq 1.64$$

or, equivalently

$$\overline{X}_{100}\geq 2+1.64\frac{S}{10}
$$

($S$ is the sample standard deviation)

Comment: Your answer is not self-consistent.  You say rejecting $H_0$ means the water is safe, yet you wrote $H_1 : \mu > 2$, which means the mercury level exceeds $2$ ppb.  These two things cannot be simultaneously true.

Comment: @heropup : rejecting $H_0$ in my system is "the water is not safe" as $H_0 \leq 2$ that is the same as $H_0=2$

Comment: You literally wrote "and you will Reject $H_0$ (**the water is safe**)."

Comment: So you would choose to assume the water is safe, allowing for instance a measured $\bar x = 2.1$ ppb even though it strictly exceeds the safety limit, because it does not furnish sufficient evidence that the water is unsafe?

Comment: @heropup : Yes I confirm, now edited (in my mind the parenthesis were referred to the meaning of $H_0$ not to the expression I will reject. Sorry if my poor English (I am Italian) bad explained what I wanted to tell...but there were also a Formal System above.

Comment: @heropup : the answer to your question is yes, This depends on which role you give to the hypothesis. In my System, the water of the City is Safe unless sufficient contrary evidences are given (it is not normal that in your Civilised City the water is unsafe for the citizens)...Am I wrong?